# Will paths with the power of two return the same shortest path using Dijkstra's?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a graph, G = (V, E) with two weight functions w1(e) and w2(e), where
w1(e) = (w2(e))^2. All edge weights are unique and positive.

> Under both weight functions, Kruskal’s algorithm will return the same
>   minimum spanning tree.

I know that kruskal is greedy and will choose the shortest/lowest cost path. Since they're positive, we will end up choosing the same MST as long as there are no paths costing 1.5 or such.

> Under both weight functions, Dijkstra’s algorithm will return the same
>   shortest path.

I'm unsure about this one. I think it will also be true, but I feel as though if we get large enough numbers, one path might actually end up larger. Can anyone confirm that if we were to exponentiate the path lengths?

Answer (score 4):

No.  Imagine two paths, one with weight 1+2+3 and one with weight 4.  Now square the weight of every edge.

Comment: This is for the Dijkstra's assumption? Can we have a path with more edges than the other? I understand that with your example we will have a different shortest path but they seem to be two different examples?

Comment: @Andrew Raleigh: I don't understand your question.  Of course you can have more than one path between two nodes; if there were only one path, finding the shortest path would be trivial.

Comment: I mean does Kruskal's algorithm hold with the assumption? And I mean in the way, you chose the Djikstra example to have 4, which would be 16. And then you gave another one that's 1, 2, and 3- which would be 1, 4, and 9. So I don't really get how your counter example works, I'm sorry :(

Comment: @Andrew Raleigh: 1+2+3 > 4 but 1+4+9 < 16, so the shortest path changes

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft , Really impressed with your knowledge of graph algo. We did talk before on a similar graph question. Your logic here is correct , can you direct us (links, books ) to a formal proof of this logic ...

Comment: @sapy: I'm not sure what you mean. This is a counterexample to the claim, so it is a formal proof.

Comment: Yes , but academically , when I gave  this answer , people did ask how did you come up with these value combinations . And I couldn't refer them to a source that how I came up with these specific values.

Comment: @sapy: I know that x² grows faster than x, so I knew the claim is unlikely to be true.  Then I tried some small examples in my head. 1+2 doesn't work (since it's not >3), but 1+2+3 > 4 does (since 1²+2²+3² < 4²).  In general, when trying to prove or disprove any mathematical claim, your first step should be to plug in some values and see if it seems to work.